# How can I test network connectivity to a Keberos KDC (UDP/88)

Tags: linux-networking, kerberos, troubleshooting, netcat, mitkerberos

How can I test network connectivity to a Keberos KDC (UDP/88)? Does Kerberos have a standard way to communicate that gives any output?

HTTP for example,

```
nc -v google.com 80
GET
```

will dump the website

```
nc -v smtp.gmail.com 587
ehlo localhost.localdomain
```

will dump the options I have (like starttls)

But kerberos, being UDP, I can't even test if the socket is open, the only way I'm able to test if there is a firewall issue is to log into the KDC, stop kerberos, and start netcat on that port

```
[user@kdc.example.com ~]$ nc -l -u 88 
[user@client.example.com ~]$ nc kdc.example.com -u 88
```